# Blending mode material in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I'm looking for a blending mode effect for a material that works like blending modes in Photoshop and other editing programs - that means material affects everything behind with blending mode effect.
[image: blending modes]

Comment: What do you mean by 'material mode effect'?

Comment: I mean that an object with material affects everything displayed behind it with blending mode, like multiply or overlay.

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible to achieve.

Comment: I suspect this is doable by using id masks for materials, and then using those in the compositor along with MapUV nodes to overlay different layers and using different blend modes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Renderers are coded to behave like materials in real world. They try to be physically correct.

Most of these effects you are describing are non-physical and cannot be achieved with real world materials. Some even don't conserve energy of light!

Only effect that can be done with materials is *Multiply*. An effect that can be done with lights would be *Add*.

This non-physically correct renderer can be surely made and programmed, but I don't know of any. I don't even know why anyone would have a need for something like that - what you want could be probably achieved in post-production using these blend modes on 2d layers.